# High shmmax value in Redhat 6.3

Tags: redhat, postgresql, kernel, shmmax

We are using Redhat 6.3 with 30G RAM to host our Postgres server.

The (default) shmmax value is 68,719,476,736

In some forums I have read that having an shmmax value larger than the RAM causes extensive paging, but in the Redhat forums it warns against changing a kernel parameter that is already configured to a value larger than the minimum requirements for an environment.

In ServerFault I've read that this probably has no impact.

So is there any impact of having shmmax value > RAM in a DB server, or the kernel understands this and handles it appropriately?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no practical implications of having `SHMMAX` > physical RAM, ***unless*** you actually start *using* that RAM.  Just be aware that if you start allocating more shared memory than your system has available RAM your system will swap (just like any other time you over-allocate RAM), which is certainly a performance killer.

Note that in recent versions of Postgres ([9.3.0 and later](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#Switch_to_Posix_shared_memory_and_mmap.28.29)) Postgres uses POSIX shared memory & `mmap()`, which reduces the demand for System V Shared Memory.
If you upgrade to Postgres 9.3 tuning the `SHMMAX` / `SHMALL` parameters can probably be avoided entirely unless you have an unusual environment (like running a few dozen Postgres clusters on one machine).